# JMS MQ JMSAdmin .binding

Tags: binding, jms, ibm-mq, mq

Is it possible to specify username and password for queue connection factory? Example [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/pim/v9r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.pim.ins.doc%2Fpim_tsk_creatingbindingsfile.html) does not describe it.

What I'm looking for is here
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdoc400/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.iseries.doc/info/ae/ae/ucli_pqcfw.html

The properies of QCF:

```
ASYNCEXCEPTION()
CCSID()
CHANNEL()
CLIENTRECONNECTOPTIONS()
CLIENTRECONNECTTIMEOUT()
COMPHDR()
COMPMSG()
CONNECTIONNAMELIST()
CONNOPT()
FAILIFQUIESCE()
HOSTNAME()
LOCALADDRESS()
MAPNAMESTYLE()
MSGBATCHSZ()
MSGRETENTION()
POLLINGINT()
PORT()
PROVIDERVERSION()
QMANAGER()
RESCANINT()
SENDCHECKCOUNT()
SHARECONVALLOWED()
SSLFIPSREQUIRED()
SSLRESETCOUNT()
SYNCPOINTALLGETS()
TARGCLIENTMATCHING()
TEMPMODEL()
TEMPQPREFIX()
TRANSPORT()
USECONNPOOLING()
VERSION()
WILDCARDFORMAT()
```

I'm trying to avoid calling createQueueConnection("user", "password") and need these details provided somehow via binding so I can call createQueueConnection()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task might be an issue. I don't know if it's even possible to configure this way.

There are some options, such as creating a wrapper factory that handles the user/password so that you don't have to pass around the password all over the code - at least. Spring has one [prebuilt](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/connection/UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.html) for that as well.

Other than that - consider migrate to SSL authentication instead and set the user on the channel through MCA - that might be easier to configure in JNDI.

Comment: It is possible to set it as jms.setStringProperty("XMSC_USERID", "mqm"); but I do not understand when I add this property manually to binding file it is not read:

qcf/RefAddr/75/Encoding=String
qcf/RefAddr/75/Content=mqm
qcf/RefAddr/75/Type=XMSC_USERID

Comment: It's not a good practice to store password in a repository. Anyone who has access to your QCF will be able to access queue manager. Worth looking to SSL authentication.

Comment: this not about practices. There's no password set anyway I only need to set the user if you are concerned.

Comment: If there is no password set - then you can use the MCAUSER on the MQ channel instead. If the JNDI stuff does not work.

Comment: it's a security exist that requires a username

Answer (score 1):

The JMS API mandates that user name and password are past in on the ConnectionFactory.createConnection call.  It is ill-advised that they be stored in the repository.